# How to pass all values from a Vector to a Sub?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vector

I have Integer values in a 3x3 matrix in the range B2:D4.

I made a nested loop checking each cell until it found an empty one (stop condition for each line read).

I can read the values from each cell and store at the positions of the vector, but when I check the values contained in the vector, only the value of the last position of the vector is displayed.

I need to get all the values to a subroutine that will work with these small vectors.

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Main()

    Dim vet(1 to 3) As Variant
    Dim lin As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    lin = 2
    col = 2
    i = 1

    Cells(lin, col).Activate

    Do Until Cells(lin, 1) = ""
        col = 2
        Do Until Cells(lin, col) = ""
            Cells(lin, col).Select
            vet(i) = Cells(lin, col).Value
            col = col + 1
        Loop
        ' At this point, when checking the vector, only contains the last value
        Call showVet(vet())
        lin = lin + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Sub showVet(ByRef v() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print (v(i))
    Next i
    ' And at this point, only the last value that was passed ...
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to increment the value of `i` after assigning value to variable in line `vet(i) = Cells(lin, col).Value`

Comment: You are missing `i=i+1` inside inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
Option Base 1

Sub Main()

Dim vet(1 To 3) As Variant
Dim lin As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lin = 2

    Do Until Cells(lin, 1) = ""
        i = 1
        col = 2
        Do Until Cells(lin, col) = ""
            .Cells(lin, col).Select
            vet(i) = Cells(lin, col).Value
            i = i + 1
            col = col + 1
        Loop

        Call showVet(vet())
        lin = lin + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub

Sub showVet(ByRef v() As Variant)
Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print (v(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```